# Chi squared test to confirm game is fair and consistent with paytable

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have a game that people can play. They play 1.0 in game currency and can win an amount of in game currency ranging from 0.0 to 25.000 in game currency. I have orchestrated it so the expected return for a customer is 0.35.

The game has been played 17000 times and the average amount of in game currency won is 0.298 of the total amount played. How can I craft a test to check whether there is some bias somewhere? I was thinking a ch i squared test but would I need to do 17000 calculations of (win - 0.35)^2/0.35 and then sum these and compare to the chi squared table with n=17000 degrees of freedom? Or am I totally off the mark?

Answer (score 1):

Chi-square test is for count data, for example the number of time a dice is rolled a 6.
What does the distribution looked like from the results of the 17000 games?  If it looks approximately normal, then calculating the z-score will determine if your game is fair.

Comment: The distribution  of the 17000 games (an estimate of the distribution of the population) does not need to be normal. What matters is that the sample distribution for the mean is approximately normal.

Answer (score 1):

With possible winnings from 0 to 25, it seems there is room for
considerable variability. Because you show no information about
frequencies of individual payouts, I don't see a rigorous way to test whether 0.298 is
significantly below the 'expected' return of 0.35.

If, for example, you had payouts of $(0, 1, 2, 50)$ with
respective probabilities $(0.768,$ $0.162,$ $0.069, 0.001),$
then the mean payout would be $0.35$ and the variance of the
payout would be $2.8155$ (SD $1.6778)$. If payouts are as highly discrete
as in my example, I would feel somewhat uncomfortable with the assumption
that the $n = 17\,000$ observations are anywhere near normal.

For my example, if the games were fairly played, then the $n$ payouts might be similar to those in the sample below, simulated using R:

```
pay; pr
[1]  0  1  2 50
[1] 0.768 0.162 0.069 0.001
set.seed(927)
y = sample(pay, 17000, p=pr, rep=T)
table(y)
y
    0     1     2    50 
13027  2796  1165    12 
mean(y)
[1] 0.3368235

summary(y)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.3368  0.0000 50.0000
```

[Note: The data are so highly skewed that the upper quartile is 0.]

Then you could do a chi-squared test to see if these observed counts
are consistent with the expected counts from the payout probabilities
for your game:

```
exp = 17000*pr; exp
[1] 13056  2754  1173    17
obs = c(13027, 2796, 1165, 12);  obs
[1] 13027  2796  1165    12
```

The chi-squared statistic $Q = 2.23$ has approximately a chi-squared distribution with 3 degrees of freedom, so the 5% critical value $c = 7.815.$
Because $Q < c$  you would accept the null hypothesis that the game is fair at the 5% level. Accordingly, the  P-value is $0.5260 > 0.05,$ also indicating that
the data are consistent with the null hypothesis.

```
q = sum((obs-exp)^2/exp); q
[1] 2.230087
qchisq(.95, 3)
[1] 7.814728
1 - pchisq(q, 3)
[1] 0.5260465
```

---

*Notes:* (a) If you you have more levels of payouts than in my example, you might
do a Z-test, where the null hypothesis is $H_0: \mu = 0.35,$ the alternative hypothesis is $H_a: \mu \ne 0.35,$ and the known population standard deviation
is $\sigma = 1.6778.$ For $n = 17000$ simulated results above the sample mean
is $\bar X = 0.3368.$ Notice that you need the known $\sigma$ in order to complete this test.

Here is Minitab output for such a z-test, using the sample mean from the
simulated data above and the standard deviation $\sigma$ computed from
the intended probabilities. It does not reject the null hypothesis that $\mu = 0.35.$

```
One-Sample Z 

Test of μ = 0.35 vs ≠ 0.35
The assumed standard deviation = 1.6778

    N    Mean  SE Mean       95% CI           Z      P
17000  0.3365   0.0129  (0.3113, 0.3617)  -1.05  0.294
```

(b) If you believe the data are sufficiently near normal, you might also do a one-sample t test, which requires the sample variance $S$ of the data. The following
output of such a test using R uses the simulated data and $S$ is computed
as part of the procedure. Again here, $H_0: \mu = 0.35$ is not rejected.

```
t.test(y, mu=.35)

        One Sample t-test

data:  y
t = -1.1884, df = 16999, p-value = 0.2347
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0.35
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.3150903 0.3585568
sample estimates:
mean of x 
0.3368235
```

(c) The argument for using a Z- or t-test here would be that the
*sample means* of $n= 17000$ games would be nearly normal. I took a look at sample means from 1000 games with my payouts: There were 583 distinct sample means among the 1000. Their histogram and density estimator (red) shown below are still noticeably right-skewed. Even so, I suppose many
statisticians would be more comfortable with normal-based tests than I am.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- The chi-square test is used to test whether the observed distribution matches your theoretical orchestrated distribution.
- When you are only interrested in the question whether the observed mean 0.298 is significantly different from 0.35 then you can use a z-test. This would be valid since the sample distribution of the observed mean will approach asymptotically a normal distribution for large $n$.

We do not have information about your theoretic distribution or your observations. But in the *worst* (largest variance) case you have

$$P(X) = \begin{cases} 0.014 & \text {if} & X=25.0\\
                        0.986 & \text {if} & X= 0.0\\
                        0 & \text {if} & X \notin \lbrace 25.0,0.0  \rbrace
 \end{cases}$$

This results in a mean value of 0.35 (your null hypothesis). And it has a variance of $$\sigma_X^2 = 0.014*0.986*25^2 \approx 8.63$$.

Then the variance of the mean of 17000 games is that value divided by 17000 $$\sigma_{\bar{X}}^2 = \frac{\sigma_X^2}{17000} \approx 5 \times 10^{-4}$$ Then the standard error $\sigma_{\bar{X}}$, will be around 0.023 and this means your observed difference, of $0.35-0.298 = 0.052$, is 2.3 times the standard error which is quite big (p value around 2.1%).

---

The underlying distribution of $X$ is not so much important. The distribution of $X$ might be discrete, but the distribution of *the mean* of 17000 *independent* draws from $X$ are not discrete and resemble a normal distribution.

(if this is like a lottery with 17000 fixed ballots, then the draws are not independent).

See this simulation:

```
set.seed(1)                       # set randomizer for replicability
x <- seq(25/17000/2,0.5,25/17000) # levels for histogram

# simulate 
samplemeanX <- replicate(10^5, mean(sample(    x = c(0,25), 
                                            size = 17000, 
                                         replace = TRUE, 
                                            prob = c(0.986,0.014))))
# plot histogram
hist(samplemeanX, 
     freq=0, breaks = x, xlim = c(0.25,0.45),col = 0+2*(x<=0.298),
     main="100 000 repetitions of 17 000 games", xlab = "mean of 17000 games")

# add curve based on Gaussian
sigma <- sqrt(0.014*0.986*25^2/17000)   # variance of the Gaussian
lines(x, dnorm(x , 0.35, sigma))        # plot the curve
```

resulting in this image:

[image: worst case example]

Note that this displays the extreme case where the prices concentrate around 0 and 25. If you have more intermediate prizes then the variance of the mean of 17000 draws will be smaller and it will be even less probable than the computed 2.1%.

Thus we can say p-value < 2.1%. (now the difficult part is how to interpret that value, is there a bias? or is this just a coincidence? .... we do not know. A statistical test can not give you a definite answer. But a reasonable person would have a certain level beyond which the coincidence is doubted and one acts as if there is a bias, even when it is not completely 100% certain.)